# ImpressPages 4: Correct way to send page data via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json, impresspages

I want to create an ajax page and I was wondering how to do it correctly? Essentialy I just need to get page data, and block content.

For now I have quick and dirty solution for the problem, by printing json in ipBeforeResponceSent Event and exiting, but it's ugly..

```
class Event{
    public static function ipBeforeResponseSent($event){
        $ajax =  ipRequest()->getQuery('ajax');
        if ($ajax){
            $page = ipContent()->getCurrentPage();

            $data['status'] = 'success';
            $data['url'] = $page->getLink();
            $data['page'] = ipContent()->getBlockContent('main');
            $data['title'] = $page->getTitle();
            $data['id'] = $page->getId();

            $data['pageorder'] = $page->getOrder();
            $data['parent'] = $page->getParentId();
            $data['timestamp'] = time();

            exit(json_encode($data, true));
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript side:

```
$.getJSON(PAGE_URL, {ajax: 'true'}, function(responce) {
    if (responce.status == 'success'){
        /***/
    }
});
```

Maybe the cleanest solution would be to just send link to my plugin's controller?

Comment: Please add more details about situation. Where this AJAX is sent from? What page data do you have to send via AJAX (page ID?)? Etc.

Comment: Added javascrpt in question. @AudriusJankauskas

Answer (score 1):

Correct usage of AJAX:

pass two parameters:

sa: 'Plugin.Action'
securityToken: ip.securityToken (if you are in javascript)

then create controller action and return json response object:

return new \Ip\Response\Json($data);

Here is all that info in details http://www.impresspages.org/docs/controller

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that if you have `PAGE_URL`, you should be able to use `page id`, too.

If this functionality is related only with this specific website, use `Application` plugin and its `PublicController.php` which is already in place.

```
public function getPageAjax()
{
    // Allowing only post actions
    ipRequest()->mustBePost();

    // Getting page ID from posted data
    $pageId = ipRequest()->getPost('pageId');

    // Get page object
    $page = ipContent->getPage($pageId);

    if ($page != null) {
        $data = array();

        // Do what you need

        return \Ip\Response\JsonRpc::result(array('data' => $data));
    } else {
        return \Ip\Response\JsonRpc::error("Page not found");
    }
}
```

Javascript would look something like this:

```
function applicationGetPageAjax(pageId) {
    var postData = {
        'pa': 'Application.getPageAjax',
        'pageId': pageId,
        'jsonrpc': '2.0'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: ip.baseUrl,
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response && response.result) {


                // Do what you want with response
                alert(response.result.data);


            } else if (response && response.error && response.error.message) {
                alert(response.error.message);
            } else {
                alert('Unknown response.');
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert('Unexpected error.' + response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

I haven't tested it. Use it as a principle. You can find multiple examples of similar AJAX actions in the core.

Comment: Well the problem is that I don't know the page id.

Comment: This is how you can get page ID ipContent()->getCurrentPage()->getId()

Comment: @TheFobas, where do you get PAGE_URL from? If it's a current page then Mangirdas have you the snippet to get ID.

Comment: @AudriusJankauskas Well I made some digging in CMS and found that I can change controller in ipRouteAction Job to my controller, praticly coppied the original job.... https://gist.github.com/TheFOBas/f25226b45adb71176032